# How to do two way binding in custom directives in Vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-resource

Hi I am looking for a solution for two way binding in Vue.js 2. I found a answer [here](http://012.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#Two-way_Directives) about two way binding but it is in Vue.js 1. I tried to work it in Vue.js 1. But it didn't work. Can anyone help me here.

Why I want that?
A - I have a contenteditable div and a span tag inside which is shows a variable with v-html. But I want some functions to call when some edit happens. @change and @keyup don't work with span in vuejs 1. So I moved to custom directives.

Answer (score 1):

To support something like this in vue2.0: as suggested by Evan You in forum [here](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/4353/the-correct-way-to-use-twoway-directive-in-vue-2-0/2) is to put these kind of functionality in a component and to reuse the same functionality on multiple components you can extract it into a shared mixin.

> My suggestion is that the logic should be handled inside the component. In 2.0 v-model can work on components, e.g. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/next/examples/select2/index.html
>
> If you want to reuse the same logic on multiple components you can extract it into a shared mixin.

Comment: page is not found.

Comment: @subha.py, Sorry I didn't check the link, use this: https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html